# How to allow UltimateListCtrl to rearrange itself, wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

how can I allow a UltimateListCtrl, to be able to reorder/rearrange itself with the users input? The following shows the ability however i am not sure how it can be done.
    DATA = {
    0 : ("3", "3", "1"),
    1 : ("2", "1", "2"),
    2 : ("1", "2", "3")
    }

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC

class MyList(ULC.UltimateListCtrl, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, columns):
        ULC.UltimateListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, agwStyle=ULC.ULC_REPORT | ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)
        self.itemDataMap = DATA
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, columns)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK, self.OnColumn)

    def OnColumn(self, e):
        self.Refresh()
        e.Skip()

    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.list = MyList(self, 3)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "A")
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, "B")
        self.list.InsertColumn(2, "C")

        items = DATA.items()
        for key, data in items:
            index = self.list.Append(data)
            self.list.SetItemData(index, key)

        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: `The following shows the ability however i am not sure how it can be done`. Could you rephrase your question ? I can not understand what the problem is. Your code works perfect as far as I can see. what `reorder/rearrange itself with the users input` means? Show what you would expect from the given entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are asking for something like this:

```
class MyList(ULC.UltimateListCtrl, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        ULC.UltimateListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, agwStyle=ULC.ULC_REPORT | ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)
        self.data = data
        self.IDoMyself()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK, self.OnColumn)

    def IDoMyself(self):
        self.itemDataMap = self.data
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, len(self.data))

        self.InsertColumn(0, "A")      # you should generalize this for any size
        self.InsertColumn(1, "B")
        self.InsertColumn(2, "C")

        for key, data in self.data.items():
            index = self.Append(data)
            self.SetItemData(index, key)

    def OnColumn(self, e):
        self.Refresh()
        e.Skip()

    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self
```

Note you should also automate the InsertColumn process to take into account the number of columns programmatically. If you dont need special column names and you are only to use a few, you could use string.ascii_uppercase to get the letter for each column.

Then you instantiate the class in your Frame:

```
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        DATA = { 0 : ("3", "3", "1"), 1 : ("2", "1", "2"), 2 : ("1", "2", "3") }
        self.list = MyList(self, DATA)
        self.Show()
```

I put DATA here but modifying the code a bit it could be send from outside with a call like MainWindow(self, DATA).

Comment: I tried the code, but when you the user tries to rearrange it, nothing happens. (by dragging element to a new location)